# how to create an asset folder in a dot42 project?

Tags: visual-studio, android-assets, dot42

I am trying to write my first application in dot42. i am using vs2010.
How to create an asset folder in dot42 project?   i need to use the asset folder to copy my own sqlite database.

any idea? any help will be appreciated.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the sqlite database to your dot42 project. go to the properties of the database file and set the Build action property to Embedded resources.

in the source code we can see the database file name in the list of assets:

```
Context context = GetApplicationContext();
String[] assetList = context.GetAssets();
```